# w3m on WSL - Can't select text using mouse

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, w3m

I am using the `w3m` text browser through WSL, on my Windows 11 machine.

I cannot select any text (for copy/paste using the Windows clipboard) shown by w3m. Neither works on Windows Terminal nor the traditional `conhost`. Copy/paste works in general terminal sessions (using wsl or cmd) but just not in w3m.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w3m enables the *mouse reporting* mode in your terminal, so that you could directly click on links or scroll the displayed page. While in this mode, most terminal apps let you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select text on the terminal layer (without passing clicks through to the program).

Comment: Thanks, it works!